# mysql help to make a report

Tags: mysql, sql

i have two table here is `table_user` and `table_feedback` like below

```
table_user
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  | john |
| 2  | tony |
| 3  | mona |

table_feedback
| id | rate | user_id |   date   |
|----|------|---------|----------|
| 1  |   1  |   3     |2015-11-2 |
| 2  |   1  |   2     |2015-11-2 |
| 3  |   1  |   3     |2015-11-1 |
```

I wanted to show report by `date` from `table_feedback` including `name` and `id` from `table_user` and all `user` will be show if table_feedback didn't contain the user id then this will be return blank data. I have idea about `inner join` and here is my query. problem is that the query return 2 row only but i need 3 row including table_user id 1 with blank column rate.
Here is my query below.

```
SELECT 
 table_user.id,
 table_user.name,
 table_feedback.rate,
 table_feedback.date
FROM table_feedback
INNER JOIN table_user
 ON table_user.id = table_feedback.user_id
WHERE table_feedback = '2015-11-2'

expected_result_table
    | user_id | name | rate |   date   |
    |-------- |------|------|----------|
    | 1       |jony  |      |2015-11-2 |
    | 2       |tony  |   1  |2015-11-2 |
    | 3       |mona  |   1  |2015-11-2 |
```

Comment: Given the sample data that you provided, what are your expected results?

Comment: wait i am adding my expected result table thanks

Comment: That's the difference between `iNNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks for adding the expected results. I updated my answer based on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this is an outer join. Anytime you find yourself thinking along the lines of "I need to see all rows from this table, regardless of a match in another table..." you should look to an outer join.

We can use an outer join to select all users, and link them to the feedbackTable in our `JOIN` clause. This will return null values for any columns in the table that don't match up. Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, t.rate, t.dateCol
FROM userTable u
LEFT JOIN feedbackTable t ON t.user_id = u.id AND t.dateCol = '2015-11-02';
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef7e4/3) example. As a side note, it is good practice not to name date columns `date` since that is a keyword in MySQL.

---

Edit based on your expected results:

To make sure the date column appears in each row, you can hardcode it into your select. If you choose to use a variable, you won't have to update the date twice each time, you can just update the declaration:

```
SET @reportDate = '2015-11-02';

SELECT u.id, u.name, t.rate, @reportDate
FROM userTable u
LEFT JOIN feedbackTable t ON t.user_id = u.id AND t.dateCol = @reportDate;
```

Here is an updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef7e4/4).

Comment: @rana7cse not a problem. If you stick with this solution, feel free to accept the answer. :) Let me know if you have any trouble with it.

Comment: another thanks for your describe can you suggest me a good resource for learn sql what you like also

Comment: @rana7cse If you'd like an actual book, I bought this about a year ago and it was worth every penny: http://www.amazon.com/Murachs-MySQL-Joel-Murach/dp/1890774685

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you need to use `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
 table_user.id,
 table_user.name,
 table_feedback.rate,
 table_feedback.date
FROM table_user
LEFT JOIN table_feedback
ON table_user.id = table_feedback.user_id
  AND  table_feedback.date = '2015-11-2'
```

Comment: yes that's work nice and i am trying to understand the different between the joins

Answer (score 0):

In order to include user without feedback you need to use [LEFT OUTER JOIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join)

```
SELECT 
 table_user.id,
 table_user.name,
 table_feedback.rate,
 '2015-11-2'
FROM table_feedback
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_user
 ON table_user.id = table_feedback.user_id
WHERE table_feedback = '2015-11-2'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do three modifications to your query:

1. Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN (to get all the users)
2. Change the table order (first the table you want to get all rows
   from)
3. As the user 1 (john) does not have any data in the second table, you
   cannot limit the rows in WHERE-clause. Do the limitation in JOIN
   instead, so it applies only to the rows that are matching the JOIN.

So:

```
SELECT 
  table_user.id,
  table_user.name,
  table_feedback.rate,
  table_feedback.date
FROM table_user
   LEFT JOIN table_feedback ON table_user.id = table_feedback.user_id and table_feedback.date = '2015-11-02'
```